# What is the interpreter looking for?

Tags: python, class, instance

I never realized just how poor a programmer I was until I came across this exercise below. I am to write a Python file that allows all of the tests below to pass without error.

I believe the file I write needs to be a class, but I have absolutely no idea what should be in my class. I know what the question is asking, but not how to make classes or to respond to the calls to the class with the appropriate object(s).

Please review the exercise code below, and then see my questions at the end.

File with tests:

```
import unittest
from allergies import Allergies

class AllergiesTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ignore_non_allergen_score_parts(self):
        self.assertEqual(['eggs'], Allergies(257).list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

1) I don't understand the "list" method at the end of this assertion. Is it the the Built-In Python function "list()," or is it an attribute that I need to define in my "Allergies" class?

2) What type of object is "Allergies(257).list"

```
self.assertEqual(['eggs'], Allergies(257).list)
```

3) Do I approach this by defining something like the following?

```
    def list(self):
        list_of_allergens = ['eggs','pollen','cat hair', 'shellfish']
        return list_of_allergens[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I don't understand the "list" method at the end of this assertion. Is it the the Built-In Python function "list()," or is it an attribute that I need to define in my "Allergies" class?

From the `.`, you can tell that it's an attribute that you need to define on your `Allergies` class—or, rather, on each of its instances.*

> 2) What type of object is "Allergies(257).list"

Well, what is it supposed to compare equal to? `['eggs']` is a list of strings (well, of string). So, unless you're going to create a custom type that likes to compare equal to lists, you need a list.

> 3) Do I approach this by defining something like the following?

```
def list(self):
    list_of_allergens = ['eggs','pollen','cat hair', 'shellfish']
    return ist_of_allergens
```

No. You're on the wrong track right off the bat. This will make `Allergies(257).list` into a *method*. Even if that method returns a list when it's called, the test driver isn't calling it. It has to be a list. (Also, more obviously, `['eggs','pollen','cat hair', 'shellfish']` is not going to compare equal to `['eggs']`, and `ist_of_allergens` isn't the same thing as `list_of_allergens`.)

So, where is that list going to come from? Well, your class is going to need to assign something to `self.list` *somewhere*. And, since the only code from your class that's getting called is your constructor (`__new__`) and initializer (`__init__`), that "somewhere" is pretty limited. And you probably haven't learned about `__new__` yet, which means you have a choice of one place, which makes it pretty simple.

---

<sub>* Technically, you could use a class attribute here, but that seems less likely to be what they're looking for. For that matter, `Allergies` doesn't even have to be a class; it could be a function that just defines a new type on the fly, constructs it, and adds `list` to its dict. But both PEP 8 naming standards and "don't make things more complex for no good reason" both point to wanting a class here.</sub>

Comment: Yes I see the typo/syntactical error. It should be "list_of_allergens[0]" The dot in "Allergies(257).list" made me think it was a "method," but you're saying it's an "attribute." That greatly helps me separate the two concepts :)

Comment: @user1473511: Methods are a kind of attribute. Loosely speaking, you can think of them as attributes that are callable like functions, and generally defined like functions. (To speak strictly, you have to understand descriptors and the class attribute access rules, which you don't want to learn yet.)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like one of the exercises from [exercism.io](http://exercism.io/).

I have completed the exercise, so I know what's involved.

**'list'** is supposed to be a class attribute of the class Allergies, and is itself an object of type `list`. At least that's one straight-forward way of dealing with it. I defined it in the `__init__` method of the class. In my opinion, it's confusing that they called it **'list'**, as this clashes with Pythons `list` type.

**snippet from my answer:**

```
class Allergies(object):

    allergens = ["eggs", "peanuts",
                 "shellfish", "strawberries", 
                 "tomatoes", "chocolate", 
                 "pollen","cats"]

    def __init__(self, score):
        # score_breakdown returns a list
        self.list = self.score_breakdown(score) # let the name of this function be a little clue ;)
```

If I were you I would go and do some Python tutorials. I would start with basics, even if it feels like you are covering ground you already travelled. It's absolutely worth knowing your basics/fundamentals as solidly as possible. For this, I could recommend [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/courses#!/all) or [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com).

Comment: Yes it is an exercise from Exercism.io. I was befuddled by the use of "list" as you pointed out. I also didn't know, as all three of you have pointed out, that "self.list" is how the syntax goes. I've been through 2 Udacity classes on Python, and neither tackled Classes!

Comment: A good while ago I did 'Intro to computer Science' on Udacity, which, at the time, dealt with classes towards the end of the course(I don't know if it still does). They were definitely one of the tougher concepts to get my head around, that's for sure. Keep going, and don't stop :)

Comment: So what is the difference syntactically between "Allergies(257).list" & "allergies.is_allergic_to('strawberries')" If I try to write "self.is_allergic_to" I get an error stating it's not callable. How is it apparent that "is_allergic_to" is a method(function) of Allergies, while "list" is just an attribute? I can't see the distinction in the syntax.

Comment: I think that this requires more explanation than I could sensibly give in these comments. I advise that you make this into a question of it's own.

Comment: @user1473511: That has different answers at different levels. It's evident from looking at the class definition because `is_allergic_to` is created by a `def` statement (like a function) inside the class. It's evident from code that uses them because the code that uses `is_allergic_to` calls it like a function. It's evident from introspection because of runtime type information (e.g., passing them to `callable` or `isinstance` or `type`, or just looking at what the `repr` looks like). And so on.

Answer (score 1):

From how it's used, `list` is an attribute of the object returned by `Allergies`, which may be a function that returns an object or simply the call to construct an object of type `Allergies`. In this last case, the whole thing can be easily implemented as:

```
class Allergies:
    def __init__(self, n):
        # probably you should do something more
        # interesting with n
        if n==257:
            self.list=['eggs']
```

Comment: Your concise example also shows "self.list" and from all three of you I am able to deduce what I must do.